# merge sort - divide and conquer algorithm using python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mergesort

I have a 2D array i wont to sort it for example:

```
array=[[b, a, c], [2, 1, 3]]
```

I want to have

```
array=[[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3]]
```

So far what I've come up with is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl4qp.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The code needs to sort each row of the matrix (2d array) separately: mergesort (array[0][...]), mergesort(array[1][...]), ...,

Answer (score 0):

```
def MergeSort(LeftArray,RightArray):

    #Initialize the variables and loop
    #Initialize Newlist of length = length(LeftArray) + length(RightArray)
    Newlist=[] # can allocate memory for elements dynamically in python
    #Initialize i=0, j=0
    i=0
    j=0

    #Loop 
    while i < len(LeftArray) and j < len(RightArray):
        try:
            if i.isaplha():
                #Sorting the list or elements 
                if ord(LeftArray[i]) <= ord(RightArray[j]):
                    Newlist.append(LeftArray[i])
                    i = i + 1
                else:
                    Newlist.append(RightArray[j])
                    j = j + 1
        except Exception:            
            #Sorting the list or elements 
            if LeftArray[i] <= RightArray[j]:
                Newlist.append(LeftArray[i])
                i = i + 1
            else:
                Newlist.append(RightArray[j])
                j = j + 1
    if i< len(LeftArray):
        while i < len(LeftArray):
            Newlist.append(LeftArray[i])
            i = i + 1
    elif j < len(RightArray):
        while j < len(RightArray):
            Newlist.append(RightArray[j])
            j = j + 1
        
    print("Merged sorted list returned by MergeSort():",Newlist)
    print("".center(50,"-"))
    return Newlist

def MergeSortAlgorithm(Array, L, R):

    print("Array Recieved to MergeSortAlgorithm(): ", Array)
    #Base Case of Recursion
    if len(Array) == 1:
        print("Returned single element: ", Array)
        return Array

    #Finding the midpoint to divide the list
    mid = ( L + R ) // 2
    print("mid point found", mid)
    print("".center(80,"-"))

    #Recursion for left and right array
    print("Calling Left side: MergeSortAlgorithm(",Array[L:mid],",", L,",", mid,")")
    print("Array: ", Array[L:mid])
    print("".center(80,"-"))
    LeftArray = MergeSortAlgorithm(Array[L:mid], L, mid)

    print("Calling Right side: RightArray = MergeSortAlgorithm(",Array[mid:R],",", 0,",", R-mid,") ")
    print("Array: ", Array[mid:R])
    print("".center(80,"-"))
    RightArray = MergeSortAlgorithm(Array[mid:R], 0, R-mid)
    
    #Return the combined result
    print("Call to MergeSort(LeftArray, RightArray) combine and return the merged result")
    print("L Array: ", LeftArray,"\nR Array",RightArray)
    
    return MergeSort(LeftArray, RightArray)

nested_list = [['b', 'a', 'c'], [2, 1, 3]]

ans=[]

for i in nested_list:
    val = MergeSortAlgorithm(i,0,len(i))
    ans.append(val)
print("Final sorted array is : ",ans)
```

Output:

Final sorted array is :  [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]]